# What is comparison of readout times of global and rolling shutter cameras?

Tags: cmos, camera, optoelectronics

Rolling shutter will take more time because of sequential readout and global will take less time.But what are the exact values of image readout time?

Comment: Why would you vote to close this on the basis of "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic"? I could see this closed as "too broad", but the "use" basis doesn't make any sense. You don't "use" a camera sensor, you select one for a design.

Comment: I think the title asking about "cameras" not sensors gives the impression that this isn't about engineering but the use of cameras.  It's borderline, but if the OP clarified the title and question as having to do with selection of a sensor it would likely not get close votes.

Answer (score 1):

The image readout rate is the frame rate of the camera in both instances.

So if your camera is 30Hz then you get a new image every 33.3 ms. It will make no difference whether you have rolling or global shuttering.

The clock rate at which data is transferred is related to the camera functionality. 
If the camera provides uncompressed data, then this will typically be the highest clock rate.

If the camera does compression of the data the clock rate will typically be slower.

Comment: Agree with Jack: "rolling/global shutter" just specifies if the pixel exposure happens globally. The readouts end up being sequential anyway.

Comment: Let ,
a=time required to expose all pixels
,  
b=time required to transfer it to target location
,  
a+b=time required for frame capture
Now:
a(Global)<a(Rolling)

......b(Global)? b(Rolling).....a+b(Global)?a+b(Rolling)....         What would be the estimated value of a+b for both cases.        Does that clear up my question?

Comment: @AnujPatil It still does not matter how you acquire/send data you get one complete set of data in each frame rate time of the camera. You can never exceed this. a is slightly longer in rolling shutter, but be would be the same. However you still get all the data in one frame time. It's worth noting that rolling shutter is used in many cameras that compress the image to reduce the amount of silicon logic required for compression.